# Target all the non firefox browsers. The easiest way

Tags: html, css, firefox, mobile, cross-browser

I want to show different code for firefox browsers and another one for all the other browsers. This include IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera and mobile browsers including all the versions.

```
<div class="firefox"> 
<p>This should be only shown in firefox browser versions.</p>
</div>

<div class="nonfirefox"> 
<p>This should be only shown in non-firefox browsers including mobile.</p>
</div>
```

It is very important both won't show up in a same browser.

I can easily do this to hide the non-firefox version.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix () { 
.nonfirefox { 
    display:none;
    }
}
```

But what's the easiest way to hide the firefox version showing in rest of the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Hide in Chrome, Safari, ...
.firefox {
    display:none;
    }

// Show in firefox
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
.nonfirefox { 
    display:none;
    }
.firefox {
    display:block;
    }
}
```